# displaying all images from firebase storage (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I can get it to display one image but go into a folder and display all images. I feel like my mapping is wrong.

From my understand `.child()` refers to a name of the file but from my understanding it can also refer to the folder that you want to access and `listAll()` tell it to list all of the files that is the file.

```
    const [sampleImage, setSampleImage] = useState(); 

    const getSampleImage = async () => {
        const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('Front/').listAll();
        const url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL().catch((error) => { throw error });
        setSampleImage(url);
    }

 
    useEffect(() => {
        getSampleImage();
    });


  return (
        { sampleImage && getSampleImage.map(Image => (
                <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }} key={imageRef.id}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: sampleImage.get(k) }} style={{ width: 350, height: 350 }} /> 
                </View>
                ))}
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`listAll()` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#listall) returns a promise of a `ListResult`, which contains a **list** of `StorageReference` items, so you'll need to await the list, loop over that, and call `getDownloadURL()` on each.

Something like:

```
const getSampleImage = async () => {
    const imageRefs = await firebase.storage().ref().child('Front/').listAll();
    const urls = await Promise.all(imageRefs.items.map((ref) => ref.getDownloadURL());
    setSampleImage(urls);
}
```

And then:

```
{ sampleImage && getSampleImage().map(url => (
    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }} key={imageRef.id}>
        <Image source={{ uri: url }} style={{ width: 350, height: 350 }} /> 
    </View>
))}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.  I'm getting an error that imageRefs.map is not a function.

Comment: Yeah, that needed an `items` in there. I highly recommend checking the reference documentation I linked, as that helps in solving such problems.

Comment: sorry about the late reply. Yes I end up figuring it out. Thank you for all of your help :)